# Multiplying Fractional Exponent with a whole

Tags: exponential-function

Studying for a math exam and I can't understand the working for this one section of a question.

$x^{\frac{1}{2}}2x =2x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ but I'm not sure how it's done, would someone kindly explain?

Comment: Do you know how to simplify $x^ax^b$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$x=x^1$$
$$x^ax^b=x^{a+b}$$

Can you go from here?

Comment: Yeah I see it now, the fraction threw me off and had me coming up with crazy ideas. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Remember that

$$x^n x^m = x^{n+m}$$